# why books list not filtered and both item with name N1 & N2 appears and how to prepare ObservableCollection

Tags: c#

I have below class and their associated data, here I am trying to filter books with book name having name "N1", but it's not working and I am getting both book items in `filterList, please suggest why and what is the best way to fill out observable collection based on filter data?

```
 var lstStudents = new List<Student>
        {
            new Student
            {
                Name = "studen1",
                Standards = new List<Standard> {new Standard {Name = "std1"}, new Standard {Name = "std2"}},
                Books = new List<Book> {new Book {Name = "N1", Page = "20"}, new Book {Name = "N2", Page = "30"}}
            },
            new Student
            {
                Name = "studen2",
                Standards = new List<Standard> {new Standard {Name = "std1"}},
                Books = new List<Book> {new Book {Name = "N1", Page = "20"}, new Book {Name = "N2", Page = "30"}}
            },
            new Student
            {
                Name = "studen3",
                Standards = new List<Standard> {new Standard {Name = "std1"}},
                Books = new List<Book> {new Book {Name = "N1", Page = "20"}, new Book {Name = "N2", Page = "30"}}
            }
        };

        var filterList = lstStudents.Where(c => c.Standards.Count == 1
                                          && c.Standards.Any(d => d.Name == "std1")
                                          && c.Books.Any(d => d.Name == "N1"))
            .ToList();
        //why both books with Name N1 & N2 both filtered as I am filtering with name = N1?

        var data = new ObservableCollection<Data>();

        foreach (var item in filterList)
        {
            data.Add(new Data { BookName = item.Name, BookPage = item.Books[0].Page });
        }
```

Supporting Classes are,

```
 public class Data
{
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public string BookName { get; set; }
    public string BookPage { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Standard> Standards { get; set; }
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Standard
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Page { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: your filter is applied for student list, so it's normal.

Comment: so how to filter for both `standard` and `Books`?

Comment: i'm adding an answer to your question, to get ``studentName``,``BookName`` and ``BookPage`` by one shoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could :
1 - Filter All`students` that have `count` of `Standards` equals `1` and name `std1`,
2 - And Flatten all `books` and `student Name` to `Data` object directly,
3 - Use second filter for book `BookName == "N1"`,
4 - Put directly the result in `ObservableCollection`, like the following code:

```
List<Data> filterList = lstStudents.Where(c => c.Standards.Count == 1 && c.Standards.Any(d => d.Name == "std1"))
    .SelectMany(x => x.Books.Select(y => new Data { StudentName = x.Name, BookName = y.Name, BookPage = y.Page }))
    .Where(d => d.BookName == "N1")
    .ToList();

var newData = new ObservableCollection<Data>(filterList);
```

**Demo**

```
foreach (Data data in filterList)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"StudentName:{data.StudentName} BookName:{data.BookName} BookPage:{data.BookPage}");
}
```

**Result**

```
StudentName:studen2 BookName:N1 BookPage:20
StudentName:studen3 BookName:N1 BookPage:20
```

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sajid. Appreciate :)

Answer (score 1):

Your query returns students that have any "N1" book in their books list (along with the other filters).

So the books themselves are not being filtered out, just students that don't have that book.

An example of how you could return a list of "N1" books for the students that meet the initial filters is:

```
var filterList = lstStudents.Where(c => 
c.Standards.Count == 1
&& c.Standards.Any(d => d.Name == "std1"))
.SelectMany(s => s.Books.Select(b =>                                                                                     
new {
    StudentName = s.Name,
    BookName = b.Name,
    BookPage = b.Page
})
.Where(b => b.BookName == "N1"));
```

Then, e.g:

```
foreach (var item in filterList)
    {
        data.Add(new Data { StudentName = item.StudentName, BookName = item.BookName, BookPage = item.Page });
    }
```

This first of all retrieves students matching the supplied criteria then retrieves the books from those students into one list of books (the `SelectMany` method).

It then filters those books to return only those with the required criteria into an anonymous type with student name also.

Comment: Thanks. How to select `Name` from `Student` then and create a list of `Data`?

Comment: Edited to add student name (similar solution as @Sajid)

Comment: Thanks a lot sir